# How to separate .csv data into different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with data which looks like this:

> NCP_341_1834_0022.png  2   0  130  512  429

I would like to split the data into different columns with names like this:

> ['filename','class','xmin','ymin','xmax','ymax']

I have done this:

```
test_txt = pd.read_csv(r"../input/covidxct/train_COVIDx_CT-3A.txt")
test_txt.to_csv(r"../working/test/train.csv",index=None, sep='\t')
train = pd.read_csv("../working/test/train.csv")
```

However when I download the .csv file, it gives me the data line all in one column, as opposed to 6 columns. How can I fix this?

Comment: why your CSV file is in a .txt file?

Comment: Thats how the labels are presented

Comment: @zampoan it is  not comma separated but space separated, so use `sep=' '` in pd.read

Answer (score 2):

Just set the right separator (',' by default):

```
test_txt = pd.read_csv(r"../input/covidxct/train_COVIDx_CT-3A.txt", sep=' ', header=None)
```

if you are using [test_COVIDx_CT-3A.txt](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hgunraj/covidxct?select=test_COVIDx_CT-3A.txt) from Kaggle.

Don't forget to set `header=None` since there is no header. You can also use `colnames=['image', 'col1', 'col2', ...]` to replace default names (0, 1, 2, ...)

Comment: Looks like maybe they tried `'\t'`, so possibly just need `' '`~

Comment: @BeRT2me. You are right: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hgunraj/covidxct?select=test_COVIDx_CT-3A.txt

Answer (score -1):

Just to answer my own question, You can use str to split the single .csv file into different columns. For me, I split it into 6 columns, for my 6 labels:

```
train[['filename', 'class','xmin','ymin','xmax','ymax']] = train['NCP_96_1328_0032.png 2 9 94 512 405'].str.split(' ', 6, expand=True)
train.head()
```

Then just drop the column you dont need:

```
train.drop(train.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

Comment: You should do this when you read the file, not later on. This also makes you lose the first line of data...